# Sequelize include return data

Tags: node.js, express, pug, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize express with Node.js as the backend. I have models Event and models buyer with relation many to many

**Model Event:**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Event = sequelize.define("Event", { //...}, 
{
            tableName: 'event',
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true,
            classMethods: {
                associate: function (models) {
                    Event.hasMany(models.Meetings, {foreignKey: 'event_id'});

                Event.belongsToMany(models.Buyer, {
                    through: 'BuyerPresent'});

                Event.belongsToMany(models.Seller, {
                    through: 'SellerPresent'});
                }
            }
        });

    return Event;
};
```

**Model Seller:**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Seller = sequelize.define("Seller", { //...
    }, {
        tableName: 'seller',
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Seller.hasMany(models.Meetings, {foreignKey: 'seller_id'});

                Seller.belongsToMany(models.Event, {
                    through: 'SellerPresent'});
            }
        }
    });

    return Seller;
};
```

I run the query and send the data with

```
res.render('path', {'results':seller})
```

:

```
function findIdSeller(selectEvent) {
    var match = {
        where: {
            event: selectEvent
        },
        // include: {
        //     model: Seller
        // },
        include: [{
            model: Seller,
            nested: false
        }],
        // plain:true

        raw: true
    };
    return models.Event.findAll(match)
}
exports.findDataSellerPromise = function (selectEvent) {
    return findIdSeller(selectEvent).then(function (result) {
        return result.map(function(seller) {
            console.log('SELLINFO: ', seller);
            return seller;
        });
    });
};
```

In the terminal i received:

```
{
    id: 4,
    incoming: 2,
    event: 4,
    'Sellers.id': 1,
    'Sellers.name_firm': 'kdm srl',
    'Sellers.site': 'www.terrebasse.com'
}
```

How can I return an item as:

```
{
    id: 4,
    incoming: 2,
    event: 4,
    Sellers: {
        id': 1,
        name_firm: 'kdm srl',
        site: 'www.terrebasse.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `return res.json(seller);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `raw: true` from the query
That would give sellers as instance on each event

Something like

```
{
   //Event1 properties
   Sellers: {
      // Associated sellers properties
    }
}
```

Guess I am too late to the party..
But for anyone else facing similar issue